# Como esse "Disco de César" consegue criptografar/descriptografar sem uma função com o alfabeto abc?

Tags: python

```
modo = ''
resultado = ''
deslocamento = ''

deslocamento = input('Qual o deslocamento: ')
 
modo = input("Você quer:\n1 - Criptografar\n2 - Descriptografar\n")


if(modo == '1'):
    texto = input("Insira o texto para Criptografar: \n")

    for i in range (0, len(texto)):
        resultado = resultado + chr(ord(texto[i]) + int(deslocamento))
        print(resultado)
        resultado = ''

if(modo == '2'):
    texto = input("Insira o texto para descriptografar: \n")

    for i in range (0, len(texto)):
        resultado = resultado + chr(ord(texto[i]) - int(deslocamento))
        print(resultado)
        resultado = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço Python, mas provavelmente está deslocando caracter a caracter com base no valor de cada um em codificação ASCII. A tabela ASCII é uma tabela de codificação de caracteres que associa caracteres (por exemplo, letras) a números, por exemplo a letra A maiúscula é o número 65, a letra B maiúscula é o número 66, etc. (Vale uma busca no Google para ver a cara que essa tabela tem, vai até ajudar a entender melhor o que está acontecendo no código).

No caso a função `ord(caracter)` caso receba a letra 'A' retorna 65 e a função `chr()` faz a conversão contrária (recebe 65 e retorna 'A').

Computadores apesar de não parecer só entendem números, não entendem letras (mas sabem representá-las graficamente através de fontes). Então é feita uma ressignificação que associa letras a determinados números de acordo com tabelas padronizadas, de forma a permitir renderizar esses números a partir de determinada fonte.

Poderia ter sido feito com um vetor de letras (alfabeto), o efeito seria o mesmo, mas a linguagem já tem essa codificação "embutida" e portanto isso não é necessário. No caso do código apresentado está permitindo codificar também números e outros caracteres, como sinais de pontuação.

Não sei se soube explicar direito mas a ideia é mais ou menos essa.

Comment: A ideia é essa, só uma observação que o código do AP pode ser [simplificado](https://ideone.com/JQUj0j)